# Create a CD Repository for ARM

Tags: repository, arm

I'm using a few different embedded systems (all ARM based) and I don't have internet access on these projects.

I've been trying to parse tutorials and I've created a local network repository in the 192.168.1.* subnet for Ubuntu 64 bit, but I can't seem to find a good tutorial for **burning an ARM package repository to a CD** so I can edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` to read from it.